# Download file from URL if not modified recently using Powershell

Tags: powershell, download, get, httpwebrequest

I have a Powershell script that is downloading files continuously from a URL public directory. The script is supposed to download files from the directory that does not currently exist in our local directory. The script looks like this:

```
$outputdir = 'C:\mydir\public\demos'
$url       = 'https://xxx.xxx.net/fastdl/xxx/xxx/public/'

# enable TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.1 protocols
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12, [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11

$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
# get the list of links, skip the first one ("../") and download the files
$WebResponse.Links | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href -Skip 0 | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Downloading file '$_'"
    $filePath = Join-Path -Path $outputdir -ChildPath $_
    $fileUrl  = '{0}/{1}' -f $url.TrimEnd('/'), $_
    
    if (Test-Path($filePath)) 
    {
        Write-Host 'Skipping file, already downloaded' -ForegroundColor Yellow
        return
    }
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileUrl -OutFile $filePath
}
```

Now, since I want to download all files from the **$url** directory I need to check one more condition. The file in the **$url** can't be modified in the last 10 minutes, if it has then the script should skip the file and download it once the last modification time is greater than 10 minutes.

I have not found any syntax that seem to be able to fit an if statement like that. Any ideas?

Comment: No after I edited the question have I not found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would change `Test-Path` to `Get-Item` so if that returns something, the file exists and you can examine its LastWriteTime property:

```
$WebResponse.Links | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href -Skip 0 | ForEach-Object {
    $filePath = Join-Path -Path $outputdir -ChildPath $_
    $fileUrl  = '{0}/{1}' -f $url.TrimEnd('/'), $_

    # set up a boolean fag to download or not
    $downloadThis = $true  
    if ($file = Get-Item -Path $filePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        # $file exists, check the LastWriteTime property
        if ($file.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10)) {
            Write-Host 'Skipping file, already downloaded' -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $downloadThis = $false
        }
    }
    if ($downloadThis) {
        Write-Host "Downloading file '$($file.Name)'"
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileUrl -OutFile $filePath
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this script is that it doesn't skip a file that we already have in our locale folder. It actually just overwrites it.

Comment: I think I might have formulated this wrong. The script should check the files from $url if the files has been modified 10 minutes ago. If they haven't, then download the file, and if they have been modified for less than 10 minutes ago should it NOT download the file yet.

Comment: @EmrikAhlström It should only overwrite it when the existing file is older than 10 minutes ago

Comment: Yea I assume I formulated that wrong. It should not overwrite anything. It should download all the files from $url under two conditions.
1. The file is not already downloaded
2. The file has not been modified for 10 minutes.

Comment: @EmrikAhlström Ah, that's quite a difference from what I thought you asked. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71284222/edit) the description of your question then

Comment: @EmrikAhlström Please do edit the question, but make it very clear what you mean by _"The file has not been modified for 10 minutes."_. If that is [1] the file you already locally have or [2] the modification date of file to download. In case of option [2]: How would you know that modification date if you do not have the file yet? Can you get details for the files still on the server to check?

Comment: It has been updated now.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to calculate time from now to the last modified time of the file. I once write a function to check a file created less than 10 mins or more than 10 mins and action accordingly, Hope fully it will help

```
#function to check whether a file is more than 10 mins age, if yes, return TRUE. If not, return FALSE
function file_age ($file){
#$file_info = Get-Item $file
$createtime = $file.CreationTime
$now = get-date

if (($now - $createtime).totalminutes -ge 10) {  
    Write-host "file [$file] created equal or more than 10 mins ago"
    return $true
    }
else
    {#Write-host  "file [$file] created within the 10 mins"
    return $false
    }
}
```